# Counting TAB key strokes in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I'm trying to set as embedded data, the number of times participants in my Qualtrics survey hit the tab key, but only on a certain block. I added, early in the survey, a new embedded data variable, called "tabcounter" and set its value to 0.

I inserted this code to the relevant block's JS, but the counter keeps on counting keystrokes in the following questions and blocks as well. How do I make it stop counting once the next block appears?

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  
  //tab counter
 var tabPressCount = 0;  
 var currentQuestionID = this.getQuestionInfo().QuestionID; 
 jQuery(document).on("keydown", function(counter){
  var key = counter.keyCode;
  if ((key==9)  &&  (currentQuestionID=='QID82')) {
   tabPressCount++;
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('tabcounter', tabPressCount); }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather improvisational solution: on survey flow, I create a new embedded value right after the block I'm interested in, and input into it the "tabcounter" embedded value I created earlier. 
That is, the old embedded value keeps on counting tab strokes all throughout the survey, but I'm getting its value only at the one point I'm interested in.
Good enough for what I'm looking for right now, but there must be a more elegant way to do this.